# Replace Values using R

Tags: r

So this is my data frame:

```
date        y        x      z       u      p
25.06.2009  0.582   1.145   0.603   26.36   0
26.06.2009  0.604   1.12    0.61    25.93   0
29.06.2009  0.647   1.108   0.647   25.35   0
30.06.2009  0.597   1.099   0.669   26.35   0
01.07.2009  0.604   1.085   0.633   26.22   0
02.07.2009  0.54    1.072   0.63    27.95   0
06.07.2009  0.543   1.048   0.57    29      0
07.07.2009  0.512   1.044   0.567   30.85   0
08.07.2009  0.496   1.029   0.533   31.3    0
09.07.2009  0.487   1.018   0.515   29.78   23
10.07.2009  0.482   1.007   0.504   29.02   66
13.07.2009  0.473   0.996   0.503   26.31   162
14.07.2009  0.471   0.985   0.503   25.02   235
15.07.2009  0.472   0.979   0.492   25.89   585
16.07.2009  0.441   0.969   0.486   25.42   668
17.07.2009  0.431   0.954   0.461   24.34   1080
20.07.2009  0.438   0.944   0.451   24.4    1883
21.07.2009  0.435   0.937   0.451   23.87   2398
```

Now I am looking for a way to replace the 0s from the variable p with e.g. 1s. Is there an easy way to do so? Is there also a possibility to replace a value with NA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. You could use:

```
d$p[d$p==0]<-1 #replace with 1
d$p[d$p==0]<-NA #OR replace with NA
```

Alternatively, you can use an `ifelse` command

```
d$p=ifelse(d$p==0,1,d$p) #replace with 1
d$p=ifelse(d$p==0,NA,d$p) #replace with NA
```

*where* `d` is your dataframe.

Comment: Many thanks to both! I tried: trading.days$CBBP1[trading.days$CBBP1==0] <- 1, where trading.days is my df and CBBP1 equals p. But when I hit View(CBBP1) it still shows me 0. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error so it's hard to say. Did you check the basics like: `trading.days` is a dataframe, `CBBP1` contains 0's, did you look at the whole dataframe using `fix(trading.days)` to see if something else changed?

Comment: Ohh I most certainly not. So first use trading.days=data.frame(here include all variables) right? Then yes CBBP1 contains 0 (its the variable p from my original question). And when I hit fix(trading.days) the data editor pops up. In there the variable CBBP1 now contains 1s instead of 0s. But if I hit View(CBBP1) it shows me still 0s?

Comment: Then `CBBP1` must be a different object from `trading.days$CBBP1`. Try `View(trading.days$CBBP1)`. Does that work?

Comment: that works perfectly fine, thanks! So if I want to run my regression now, I allways have to type trading.days$CBBP1 like for example:  `reg1 <- lm(y~x+z+u+trading.days$CBBP1` instead of just using CBBP1 in the regression?

Comment: yes or add `lm(..., data=trading.days)` and just call `CBBP1` instead of `trading.days$CBBP1`. Please don't forget to accept an answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are storing your data in a data frame, then you could accomplish this with:

```
df$p[df$p==0] <- 1
```

In the above example your data frame would be called df. If you would like to replace a value with NA, just put NA (unquoted) where the 1 is.