# Find and replace in R for categorical variables

Tags: r, string, atomic

```
x1 <- c("agree","disagree","agree","agree","agree","disagree","disagree")
```

How to replace `agree=1` and `disagree=0` for large atomic vectors or specific row/columns in a data frame?

Comment: Some duplicates to get you started: [duplicate 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3905038/903061), [duplicate 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29562455/903061), [duplicate 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17717864/903061), also see `?replace` or `?factor`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```
ifelse(x1 == 'agree', 1, 0)
```

More conditions can be added as necessary.

Comment: While this works (and it’s my preferred option in this simple case), adding more options is actually quite a hassle; this solution thus doesn’t scale very well beyond two values. `switch` alleviates this — but only somewhat, since the function is restricted to very specific input. The more general solution in R is to use factors.

Comment: Yes, as.factor() is correct way to handle categorical data. But the question was very specific.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `+` to convert the logical to binary

```
+(x1=="agree")
```

Or using `as.integer` (as per comments)

```
as.integer(x1 == "agree")
```

This method is much faster than the `ifelse`.

```
 set.seed(24)
 x2 <- sample(c("agree", "disagree"), 1e7, replace=TRUE)
 system.time(+(x2=="agree"))
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #  0.32    0.06    0.40 
 system.time(ifelse(x2=="agree", 1,0))
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #   3.20    0.91    4.10
```

Comment: I need to get used to starting a statement with a +. :)

Comment: @user3949008 - No, you really shouldn't.  `as.integer()` is more appropriate.

Comment: “no need”, sure. But no need for your solution either, which is after all much less explicit and thus less readable, and relies on a purely incidental type conversion to achieve the desired effect. In other words, too “clever”. I **really** discourage this solution. Know about it if you wish. Just please never use it.