# very slow For, if else if statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have a very large table (`n=2,723,860`) and I want to calculate positive wind direction (0 to 360 degrees) from negative wind direction (-180 to 180 degrees).

One of my loops, a for loop with a nested if and else if statement, takes forever to run (see below).

I am new to R and I am thinking that I just don't have this structured efficiently. Any help on how to better structure this so that it doesn't take so long (currently at 20 minutes and it still isn't done)?

```
for (j in 1:n){
  if (Jun012015$D[j] < 0){
   Jun012015$D1[j] <- (Jun012015$D[j] * (-1))
  } else if (Jun012015$D[j] > 0){
      Jun012015$D1[j] <- ((Jun012015$D[j] * (-1)) + 360)
  } else {
      Jun012015$D1[j] <- 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Yourcodewillbemorereadableifyouuseyourspacebar. :)

Comment: I just noticed that sometimes you use Jun012015$D and sometimes Jun012015$D1.  Is that a typo or were you trying to store into different variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope docendo discimus decides to reopen their answer because it was good.  Here is the code from their answer (which I will remove if they reopen theirs)

```
idx1 <- Jun012015$D < 0
idx2 <- Jun012015$D > 0
idx3 <- Jun012015$D == 0

Jun012015$D1[idx1] <- Jun012015$D[idx1] * (-1)
Jun012015$D1[idx2] <- (Jun012015$D[idx2] * (-1)) + 360
Jun012015$D1[idx3] <- 0
```

I prefer this answer for people that don't grasp vectorization yet.  It works and shouldn't be too much slower than mine (shown below). But I think it shows the process much more clearly and could help OP more in the future  than mine which probably just looks like a mystery to somebody that is still using for loops and if statements.  But here is my one-liner that should get it done:

```
Jun012015$D*(-1) + 360*(Jun012015$D > 0)
```

you would need to store that into a variable or overwrite Jun012015$D with it.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thank you Dason for this very useful and straight forward solution. I was definitely over thinking it.

Comment: @MKWalsh I wouldn't say you are overthinking it.  It just seems like you're not quite used to working with things in a vectorized fashion yet.  Eventually you'll come to a point where using for loops is fairly rare in your R programming.

Comment: Here's another suggestion that Docendo re-open his answer.  "Fancy" arithmetic is fast and has its place, but his answer is more general and more readable.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Agreed!

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `ifelse` (but this will be considerably slower compared to @Dason's solution).

```
with(Jun012015, ifelse(D1 < 0, D1 * -1, ifelse(D1 > 0, D1 * -1 +360, 0)))
```

Or as @Dason suggested, a single `ifelse` can also fit into

```
with(Jun012015, ifelse(D1 <=0, D1 * -1, D1 * -1 + 360))
```

as 0 * (anynumber) = 0.

Comment: We could probably simplify to a single `ifelse` if you change the first comparison to `<=` instead of `<`.

Comment: @Dason Thanks, it is much nicer, but according to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658775/find-and-replace-in-r-for-categorical-variables/34661155#34661155), doing some golfing got me negative votes.

Comment: I don't see any negative votes on that answer.  Anyhow I'll be honest and say that I prefer your solution on that linked question to the ifelse solution.

Answer (score -2):

Try using ifelse rather than nested if else statements.

```
for(j in 1:n){
  ifelse(Jun012015$D[j] < 0, Jun012015$D[j]*(-1), 
         ifelse(Jun012015$D[j] > 0, (Jun012015$D[j] * (-1)) + 360, 0)
}
```

Please provide some sample data that you're running this loop on to help give benchmarked answers. The apply family of functions always work better than loops in R.

Comment: There isn't any need to use the for loop in this case.  This is essentially a slowed down version of akrun's answer.

Comment: The last line is also incorrect.  `apply` isn't magic.  It still runs a loop.